# Getting an exception while calculating difference between two dates in Linq

Tags: c#, mysql, entity-framework, date-difference, dbfunctions

I am trying to get the duration between two dates in mysql.

I have observed that there is [DbFunctions](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.entity.dbfunctions(v=vs.113).aspx) class which can calculate difference between two dates in different forms like days, hours, microseconds and many more.

I am using MySQL as dabatase and EF6. 
I have used [DbFunctions](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.entity.dbfunctions(v=vs.113).aspx) as below as below.

```
await (from o in Order
  select new
  {
      ID = o.ID,
      OrderBookTime = o.OrderDateTime,
      DelieveryTime = DbFunctions.DiffHours(o.DeliveryDateTime, o.OrderDateTime),
  }).ToListAsync();
```

It throws an exception as `FUNCTION database_name.DiffDays does not exist`

I have checked the query executed in the background.

```
SELECT
`Extent1`.`ID`, 
`Extent1`.`OrderDateTime`,
DiffHours(`Extent1`.`DeliveryDateTime`, `Extent1`.`OrderDateTime`) AS `C1`, 
FROM `order` AS `Extent1`
```

Is it necessary to write custom function in the database which will calculate the difference for tow dates?

Comment: i guess you should implement it in database.

Comment: I'm pretty sure that Entity Framework is geared more towards MSSQL.  You could also eat the overhead, convert to `string` and compare.

Comment: Why does your `DiffHours` convert to `DiffDays`? What driver are you using? DevArt apparently supports `DiffDays` but not `DiffHours`.

Comment: Have a look at this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30235304/how-to-use-canonical-functions-in-entity-framework-and-mysql

Comment: Calculate this difference on client side.